# Is $T$ continuous and has closed graph?

Tags: functional-analysis, closed-graph

$T:C^1[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ is defined by $T(x(t))=x'(t)+\int_{0}^{t} x(t)\, dt$

Is $T$ continuous and has closed graph?

$x(t)=t^n$ then $T$ is not bounded and hence not continuous and has not closed graph. am I right?

Comment: Write down the norm for $C^1[0,1]$ and check how $|T(x)(t)|$ is related to it.

Comment: suppppppppppppp norm in both

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$
\|Tx\|_{C[0,1]} \leq \|x'\|_{C[0,1]} + \|x\|_{C[0,1]} 
\leq c \|x\|_{C^1[0,1]},
$$
for some constant $c$ that depends on the exact definition of the $C^1$ norm you are using,
and so $T$ is continuous and hence has a closed graph.

Here you made a mistake because I think you did not notice that the domain of $T$ is $C^1$, so you can bound $Tx$ in terms of the $C^1$ norm of $x$. In particular, having a derivative of $x$ is not so dangerous.

Another thing to note is that in general an operator can be not continuous but still have closed graph.

Comment: I would like to ask your comments in the following question math.stackexchange.com/questions/482684/… Thank you for your kind help

Comment: I don't understand the last right  side inequality, please explain a bit more.

Comment: @Tojamaru: What estimate do you need to prove in order to show that $T$ is continuous?